# Razor helper to Spark

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, spark-view-engine

hi there I'm having some trouble rewriting this code in spark, we have a website which uses both Spark and Razor, so when we do anything in razor it has to change in spark as well.
I have been using macros for spark but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the Razor code

```
@helper ImageFeature(INavigationNode node)
{
    <figure>
        <a href="@node.NavigationUrl">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ImageUrl))
            {
                <img src="@node.ImageUrl" alt=""/>
            }
            <figcaption>@Html.Raw(node.Content)</figcaption>
        </a>
    </figure>
}
```

Here is the Spark

```
<macro name="ImageFeature" node="INavigationNode">

   <figure>
          <a href="${node.NavigationUrl}">
        <if condition="(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ImageUrl))">


                  <img src="%{node.ImageUrl}" alt=""/>
          </if>
              <figcaption>${Html.Raw(node.Content)}</figcaption>
          </a>
      </figure>
</macro>
```

What do I change to make it work in spark?

So far I get this error:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3283b8a3\90ba10e3fe4a4a67979bb48611718cb7-1.cs(33,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'INavigationNode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

INavigatonNode is a type

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it, I was missing a reference